# Data structure/algo for fast insertion and counting

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I'm looking for a data structure/algorithm that allows both logarithmic insertion of elements into data structure, and logarithmic counting of elements in data structure that are smaller than a given `value`.

For instance, `std::set<int>` allows logarithmic insertion, and logarithmic `iter = std::upper_bound(..., value)` but then `distance(iter, set.begin())` is linear...

Can it be done using C++ STL containers?

Comment: Any binary tree can do this.  Write yourself an AVL tree that keeps track of the children below each node.

Comment: @AlexReinking Is there a way to implement it via C++ STL containers?

Comment: Maybe but that's a different question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree .  There isn't one in STL

Comment: @MattTimmermans - good link. Didn't know it had a name.

Comment: The C++ library offers a collection of containers with specific behavior.  None of them can be shuffled in some particular manner in order to implement a container with these characteristics. This data structure, and its logic, will need to be implemented from the ground up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, unfortunately only for `GNU C++`. Called `Policy based data structure`.

I'll show basics of usage.

```cpp
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
using namespace std;

typedef tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag,
             tree_order_statistics_node_update>
    indexed_set;

int main() {
    indexed_set s;
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(5);
    s.insert(10);
    s.insert(20);
    s.insert(21);

    cout << s.order_of_key(10) << '\n';
}
```

`order_of_key` returns the number of values in a set that are strictly smaller than the value passed.

Further information: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080